# Finding specific probability from a given conditional probability

Tags: probability

> Three girls A,B,C are going to meet.
>
> C is never late.
>
> The probability that no one will late is $0.4$
>
> If it is known that at
> least one of the girls will be late then Pr(B late) = $0.6$
>
> If it is
> known that B is late then Pr(ONLY B is late) = $5\over6$
>
> Let X be the number of girls that are late.

What is $P(X=1)$?
What is the variance of X?

I tried to use the conditional probability formula but I got that Pr(B) > $1$ and I don't see what is wrong in my calculations.

Thanks in advance

My calculation: (P(B) means B is late, P(A) means A is late)

$P(B|B\cup A)={P(B)\cap P(B\cup A)\over P(B\cup A)}=0.6$

$P(A^c|B)={P(A^c\cap B)\over P(B)}={5\over6}$

I'm bad with the MathJax syntax here but overall I tried to find P(B) out of those two equations but I have some variables that do not cancel so I can't find it

Comment: How did you get $P(B)>1$ ?

Comment: @lulu I did a mistake with some wrong assumption I tried so many ways that I don't find that way now :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that (up to LaTeX typos), I agree with your statements.  You didn't mention the first condition that the probability that no one is late is $\frac{2}{5}$, so I will include that here:

$$P(A^c\cap B^c)=1-P(A\cup B)=\frac{2}{5}$$

Therefore, $P(A\cup B)=\frac{3}{5}$.

Since $P(B|A\cup B)=\frac{3}{5}$, I agree that it follows that

$$
\frac{3}{5}=P(B|A\cup B)=\frac{P(B\cap(A\cup B))}{P(A\cup B)}.
$$

Since $B\cap (A\cup B)=B$, this means that $\frac{3}{5}=\frac{P(B)}{3/5}$ so $P(B)=\frac{9}{25}$.

I also agree that $P(A^c|B)=\frac{5}{6}$.  Therefore,
$$
\frac{5}{6}=P(A^c|B)=\frac{P(A^c\cap B)}{P(B)}.
$$

Since $P(A^c\cap B)=P(B)-P(A\cap B)$, we know that $\frac{5}{6}=1-\frac{P(A\cap B)}{9/25}$.  Therefore, $P(A\cap B)=\frac{25}{54}$.

From this, you should be able to compute $P(X=1)$ by computing $P(A\cup B)-P(A\cap B)$.

Comment: Thanks my problem was I didn't realize that $B\cap (A\cup B)=B$ and I thought that I need to find $P(A)$ too. is it possible to find $P(A)$? it is not a problem for the $P(X=1)$ question, but it may hinder the variance calculation no? how do I calculate the variance here? is there a formula or I need to first find out the expectancy and then do the $E[X^2]-(E[X])^2$

Comment: Sure, you can find $P(A)$ using inclusion and exclusion.  More precisely, $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$.  Knowing $P(X=0)$, $P(X=1)$, and $P(X=2)$ will allow you to compute the expectations using the definition.